# IIS 6 405 error when POSTing through I-Frame

Tags: iframe, post, error, aspx, iis6

Before I begin, I must add that I am more of a programmer, so please be patient :p

I have a 2003 server running IIS 6. I am trying to create a Facebook application that accesses a url on my server through an I-Frame. However, Facebook is trying to send some data via POST to my page. I assumed it wouldn't be a problem since the page is .html, but I keep receiving 405 errors (Incorrect Verbs) when trying to access it. Since these are generated by IIS, I had hoped there would be a way for me to allow html files to accept POST.

However, after a lot of Googling, it seems like that isn't possible, so instead I figure I can convert the page to an aspx one, and that should work... however I am running in to the same issue. I thought that simply adding POST to the .aspx entry in Application Extension Mapping would work, but it still doesn't.

Does anyone know what the problem could potentially be?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly IIS Rewrite (http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) allows you to change how you present URLs. Secondly fix the 405's http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216493

Comment: This seems to only effect IIS4 and IIS5 as per the kb article. But I will check out url-rewrite. I did get this working in the end somehow, but it was by changing how facebook accessed the application instead of changing anything on the server. I will try this and let you know how it goes

Comment: Bottom line is that you shouldn't be getting 405s. Good luck.